# OAuth2 bot registration with messaging end point

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We have an on-prem messaging endpoint which the botframework needs to register and communicate for chat activities. Our messaging endpoint is protected by Oauth2 over 2way SSL. We have noticed advanced options to connect to endpoint using Generic Oauth2 but looks like it expects client_id & client_secret which suggests standard OAuth2 over https.

Our security architecture insists any outbound communication outside the DMZ be 2-way SSL. Please suggest we can establish a connectivity with Ping federate over 2-way SSL using Oauth2. Appreciate any help..!

[Screenshot of Generic Oauth2 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxOS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be with the "Oauth 2 Generic Provider". It's a bit confusing given the similarity in names, but "Generic Oauth2" has similar expectations to AAD (especially, AAD v2). The "Oauth 2 Generic Provider" can be used with any generic OAuth 2 service provider and has the most flexibility, but requires the most configuration parameters.

It will take some playing with, but you may find success in trying different configurations. Otherwise, you may have to develop a custom Oauth implementation to satisfy the two-way SSL requirement. In that case, this [post](https://blog.cloudboost.io/implementing-mutual-ssl-authentication-fc20ab2392b3) *may* be of help.

Please note, the "Scope List Delimiter" at this time (due to a bug) should be set to ",".

Hope of help!